# NAN values appears when including a new padding token in my tokenizer

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, language-model, gpt-2

I'm trying to fine-tune a DialoGPT model on a new dataset. I already processed my data correctly and adding a new padding token in the tokenizer didn't seem to make any issue :

```py
#my dataset : 
print(dataset)
print(dataset[0]['text'])
```

> #### output
>
> Dataset({
> features: ['text'],
> num_rows: 48423
> })
>
> [speaker 1]: Great that you wish to hear the voices of the guitarists. Here are your booking details of the tickets. You wish to purchase 4 tickets for the event The Original Wailers that is going to take place on March 8th in Berkeley, right?
> [speaker 2]: Yup, you're right. Please May I know where is the event conducted and I need the complete address?
> [speaker 1]: Please note down the complete address of the event happening. It's at Cornerstone Craft Beer & Live Music, 2367 Shattuck Avenue. Your reservation is successful and have a great time there!
> [speaker 2]: Thanks much for the information you've given. Please can you help me to find some intermediate priced restaurant that provides Ethiopian kind of food.
> [speaker 1]: Yup! There is an Ethiopian Restaurant named Addis Restaurant providing excellent and authentic traditional Ethiopian cuisine located in Berkeley. Do you wish to reserve a table here?
> [speaker 2]:

```py
#tokenizing and adding labels
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"],  padding='max_length', add_special_tokens =True, max_length=246) #truncation=True, max_length=13)

tokenized_datasets = ds.map(
    tokenize_function, batched=True, num_proc=4, remove_columns=["text"]
)

tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.add_column("labels", tokenized_datasets[:]['input_ids']) 

train_set = model.prepare_tf_dataset(
    tokenized_datasets,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=1,
)
sample = train_set.as_numpy_iterator()
sample = sample.next()

print(tokenized_datasets)
print(train_set)
print(sample)
```

> #### output
>
> Dataset({
> features: ['input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'labels'],
> num_rows: 48423
> })
>
> <PrefetchDataset element_spec=({'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 246), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), 'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 246), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(1, 246), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
>
> ({'attention_mask': array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
> 'input_ids': array([[   58,  4125,  3110,   352,  5974,   314,   765,   284,   711,
> 440,  9190,   440, 14918,   440,  3825,   319,   616,  3359,
> 13,   198,    58,  4125,  3110,   362,  5974,   921,   765,
> 284,  3350,   262,  3496,   440,  9190,   440, 14918,   440,
> 3825,  4291,   262,  3195,    11,   826,    30,   198,    58,
> 4125,  3110,   352,  5974,  1320,   318,   826,    13,  1867,
> 2099,   286,  3496,   318,   340,    30,   198,    58,  4125,
> 3110,   362,  5974,   632,   318,  5610,   739,   262, 12136,
> 6536,   290,   534,  3496,   468,  2067,    13,   198,    58,
> 4125,  3110,   352,  5974, 20558,   617,  1637,   329,   502,
> 13,   198,    58,  4125,  3110,   362,  5974,   220, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257]])},
> array([[   58,  4125,  3110,   352,  5974,   314,   765,   284,   711,
> 440,  9190,   440, 14918,   440,  3825,   319,   616,  3359,
> 13,   198,    58,  4125,  3110,   362,  5974,   921,   765,
> 284,  3350,   262,  3496,   440,  9190,   440, 14918,   440,
> 3825,  4291,   262,  3195,    11,   826,    30,   198,    58,
> 4125,  3110,   352,  5974,  1320,   318,   826,    13,  1867,
> 2099,   286,  3496,   318,   340,    30,   198,    58,  4125,
> 3110,   362,  5974,   632,   318,  5610,   739,   262, 12136,
> 6536,   290,   534,  3496,   468,  2067,    13,   198,    58,
> 4125,  3110,   352,  5974, 20558,   617,  1637,   329,   502,
> 13,   198,    58,  4125,  3110,   362,  5974,   220, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
> 50257, 50257, 50257]]))

The ouputs so far seem pretty clean for me. But when I try to make a prediction with my model or train it I have nan values as output :

```py
#Instatiation of model 
from transformers import TFAutoModelForCausalLM
model = TFAutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-medium")

optimizer = AdamWeightDecay(learning_rate=1e-9, weight_decay_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, jit_compile=True)
```

```py
#model inference
loss = model(sample[0], labels=sample[1])
print(loss)
```

> #### output
>
> TFCausalLMOutputWithCrossAttentions([('loss',
> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([nan], dtype=float32)>),
> ('logits',
> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 246, 50258), dtype=float32, numpy=
> array([[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> ...,
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)>),
> ('past_key_values',
> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1, 16, 246, 64), dtype=float32, numpy=
> array([[[[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> ...,
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
> ```
>                                             [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>                                              [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>                                              [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>                                              ...,
>                                              [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>                                              [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>                                              [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>                                              .............
> ```

```py
#model training
model.fit(train_set, epochs=1)
```

> #### output
>
> 56/48423 [..............................] - ETA: 2:27:49 - loss: nan

This NAN value is certainly caused by the new token '[PAD]' added but I don't know how to deal with it.
Can someone help me please ?